# Use checkbox to filter data

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, filter

I want when the checkbox or button (both at the top of this screen) is checked, it does not show the items that are "Canceled" or "Received" in the Status column.

[image: picture]

Items names:

1. status search box is called "S_Status"
2. status dropdown menu is called "Status"
3. the dropdown option is pulled from Query "N_Q_PlacingOrders_Status" which pulls from Table "N_T_Placing Orders_Status".
4. Checkbox name is "CheckBox"

I tried the code below but I know I am missing a couple things that I have not been able to find in other blogs/forums.

```
Private Sub CheckBox_Click()
    If CheckBox = True Then
        DoCmd.ApplyFilter , Status = True
        If CheckBox = False Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were on the right track. Two things of note:

1) In the following code, these lines (`If CheckBox = False Then |Exit Sub |End If`) are basically pointless, unless you want the False to actually do something, its just extra fluff. Therefore, removing the secondary If statement is beneficial.

```
If CheckBox = True Then
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter , Status = True
End If
```

2) Using filters in this situation may not be the easiest way to accomplish your goal. Try this:

```
If CheckBox = True Then
    Status.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM N_Q_PlacingOrders_Status WHERE " & _
        "Status NOT IN ('Recieved', 'Cancelled')"
End If
```

*NOTE: It may need a modification to the SELECT statement, as required by the rows you are trying to pull (but I don't have that information).*

Comment: Hi Jiggles, Thank you very much for your help! It worked!